# opencart category quantity discount

Tags: php, opencart, bulk, discount

I want to set discount is as follows.

Suppose, My one product is for £4.29.
If buyer buys 3 or in multiple of 3 like 3,54,39 or 189 etc, will cost him as £3.33/product.
If buyer buys bulk order other than multiple of three like 4 or 14 or 2 or 38 etc, than it will cost him as regular price of £4.29/product.

*** One product will cost £3.33 only and only if bulk order is made with multiple quantity of 3. ***

I found some setting in the discount section of each product. It works fine as per my requirement. (reffer attached image)

![enter image description here][1]

But it's hard to mention it for each multiple of 3. For Eg. What if a customer wants to 300 products. For that I need to write till the 300.

Is there any extension available for this or any one have other solution for this problem.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Instead of implementing anything or finding stupid solutions I would copy the original product and set the minimum amount to be ordered to 3 with a new price 3.33 per piece. In this case you have two products, one for 4.29 that could be bought in any amount and another one that could be bought only in multiples of 3 for 3.33. Easy, done in 5 minutes, working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If am getting you right, you are able to calculate discount for all other quantities except for those in multiples of 3.
If that is the case, my suggestion is:

```
qty;
if ((qty % 3) == 0) {

// multiply qty by 3.33
price = qty * 3.33;
}
else {
// use your existing (working) formula
}
```

I hope this works.

Answer (score -1):

twist added into the problem.

There are three categories with same price. Assume that its £4.29.

If a customer buys any of these category product with a total quantity of 3 or multiple of 3 than one product price will be £3.33 
If a customer buys 10 products than 9 products will cost him as £3.33/product and remaining 1 product will cost £4.29.

Customer is allowed to buy 3 diffrent products of three different categories or he may buy 2 from one category or 1 from another category.

I hope you guys will understand the problem and give the bestest solution possible.